# Append a rule to a k8s ingress object

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

We have a kubernetes `Ingress` object defined. All the ingress rules are not available when defining object for the first time, hence we would like to append rules to it on the fly when configuring respective services to use with it.

Example:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: ${acm_arn}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  name: ${ingress_name}
  namespace: ${namespace}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: api.${region}.infra.${hosted_zone}
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
               name: istio-ingressgateway
               port:
                number: 80
            path: /*
            pathType: Prefix
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
               name: nginx-ingress-controller
               port:
                number: 80
            path: /*
            pathType: Prefix
```

The above object is created in the beginning. Now, we would like to append a third rule to it at later point in time.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
  name: ${ingress_name}
  namespace: ${namespace}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: api.${region}.${some_dynamic_variable}.${hosted_zone}
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
               name: istio-ingressgateway
               port:
                number: 80
            path: /*
            pathType: Prefix
```

I could have used `kubectl patch` but because the merge strategy is not specified in the [api docs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/master/api/openapi-spec/swagger.json), I understand it follows the merge strategy `replace` which is not what I intend to do.

What is the best available option to get this issue resolved?

Comment: you can `kubectl patch --type=merge`, does it work for you?

Comment: @whites11 no it does not. It overrides the 3rd rule over the existing ones and I am left with only the 3rd rule

Comment: have you looked into `kustomize`, it allows to do exactly what you are looking for, it's also built-in into `kubectl`

Comment: We are using kustomize to create all kubernetes objects. I know I can patch merge overlays into bases, but how do I patch merge something to existing objects in k8s

Answer (score 2):

There is a `kubectl` plugin called [`ingress-rule`](https://github.com/pragaonj/ingress-rule-updater). It allows you to configure an Ingress on the command line.
The plugin is available via [`krew`](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/). If you have `krew` installed simply install the plugin with:

```
kubectl krew install ingress-rule
```

Add a new rule to a existing Ingress:

```
kubectl ingress-rule -n $NAMESPACE set $INGRESSNAME --service $SERVICENAME --port 80 --host $HOST
```

Delete the previously added rule:

```
kubectl ingress-rule -n $NAMESPACE delete $INGRESSNAME --service $SERVICENAME
```